# How to show the QR Code in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use this formula to create a QR Code in Google Sheets using multiple cells (A-E). The string has no errors but the QR image does not show.  What am i missing?

```
=image("https://image-charts.com/chart? chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=" & "Name"&A2 & "%0ALast"&B2 & "%0AID"&C2 & "%0AOccupation"&D2 & "%0ACompanyAddress"&E2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One unwanted space, look at `chart?chs`
Full formula:

```
=image("https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=" & "Name"&A2 & "%0ALast"&B2 & "%0AID"&C2 & "%0AOccupation"&D2 & "%0ACompanyAddress"&E2)
```